# Why is GNU C Library called an implementation of C standard library?

Tags: implementation, glibc, standard-library

Doesn't **GNU C Library** (`glibc`) include an implementation of **C POSIX library**, which is a superset of **C standard library**? So, it seems `glibc` is much "larger" than a "*C standard library*". Can you use the word "*implementation*" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you use the word "implementation" in this case?

Yes, because it does *implement* each and every portion of the C Standard Library.

This makes sense, given that it's a superset of the standard library.